# Как поделиться файлом

Tags: java, android

Как сделать вызов вот такой штуки, что бы можно было добавить файл со смартфона и отправить на сервер. Как в Skype, OneDrive. В Google <strike>меня забанили</strike>, не смог найти ответ.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: (Мимо проходил, у меня даже андроида нет.) Если такой интерфейс есть в мелкомягких приложениях и отсутствует в приложениях других производиетелей, это признак того, что это кастомный диалог, реализованный мелкомягкими. Если верить гуглу, некий share intent, чтобы это ни значило, приводит к появлению диалога другого вида. Вероятно, вам стоит попробовать реализовать подобный функционал вручную.

Comment: Сначала я так же подулмал, что такое реализовали только мелкомягкие, но потом проверил и такое есть и в Gmail

Comment: Хм... Декомпилировать пробовали? :)

Comment: неа, я днище в этом

Comment: Ну для джавы какие-то же инструменты есть для декомпиляции? Если приложение не защищено, то это довольно простая операция.

Comment: я думаю приложения гугла и мелкомягких защищены, но я попробую посмотреть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ. Короче не правильно гуглил :(

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("file/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
```